# What is the tie b/w order of an element and even/odd permutation of a symmetric group?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If you take a symmetric group (S6), how do you find an element of particular order (e.g., 6) such that it's an even permutation?

Is there a theorem or a rule which relates order of an element to even/odd permutation of that element?

Thanks!

Comment: An permutation of odd order is even!

Comment: Does that mean if an element has order 6, even permutation of that element is not possible?

Comment: $6$ is not odd.